# WCF: The type initializer for System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility threw an exception

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

I want to test my WCF service but I'm getting this error:

> `System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.'`

I reference my WCF service to my test class(WSTester).

And this is the Inner Exception:

> ```
> **ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section compile.**
> ```

I'm new to WCF. I think my App.config file is wrong but i don't know how to implement it. I tried it in a browser. It worked, but not in a console app.

This is test program  in my WSTester :

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.Name = "dsfsfsdf";
        c.SurName="asdass";
        c.Age = 12;
        client.CreateCustomer(c);
    }
}
```

And here is my App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <compile debug="true">
  </compile>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="99" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
      </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.xx:7767/Service1.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="WorkWS.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And Web.config file under webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>

    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;;Initial Catalog=FirstProject; User Id = aykut ; password= ****</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="HBM_ASSEMBLY" value="BusinessEntities" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="WebService.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Meta veri bilgilerini açığa çıkarmaktan kaçınmak için, dağıtımdan önce aşağıdaki bilgileri false yapın -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- Hatalarda hata ayıklamak amacıyla özel durum ayrıntıları almak için aşağıdaki değeri true yapın.  Özel durum bilgilerini açığa çıkarmaktan kaçınmak için dağıtımdan önce false yapın -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>


    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="Iesi.Collections" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />

      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

At last this is my Service1.svc:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "CreateCustomer",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FAIL");
        }
        CustomerManager cm = new CustomerManager();
        cm.CreateCustomer(customer);

        return customer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining about the

```
  <compile debug="true">
  </compile>
```

element in your `app.config`, which is invalid. Just remove it.

Incidentally, where did it come from?

Comment: I think that's a different question. :-). Shouldn't your contract in your app.config be `WebService.IService1` instead of `WorkWS.IService1`

Comment: OK, fair enough. Have you looked in the server (IIS?) logs for the detail of what actually was requested at the server?

Comment: Well, you'll need to turn IIS logging on for your WCF application in IIS otherwise you'll find all sorts of things difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Search for the URL your client is posting to, which I think is `http://192.168.0.xx:7767/Service1.svc`. Or just `Service1.svc' and see if the URL looks correct in the logs. Post the log entries here if you can.

Comment: What happens if you type `http://192.168.0.xx:7767/Service1.svc?wsdl` in your browser address bar?

Comment: OK, that looks fine. My only suggestion really is, as I said above, cobble together a new question regarding the 400 HTTP Response as this question title doesn't reference that and it's been marked as having an answer so it won't attract much interest.

Answer (score 0):

When Service1.svc?wsdl write in URL

```
    <wsdl:service name="Service1"/>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```